# Where did the necromutants go?

Tags: mutant-chronicles

In Mutant Chronicles:

> The supposed bomb to destroy the machine, launches a rocket sending the machine into space.

Which planet is it aimed at? Is it ever explained how it's aimed at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spoiler

> It should be Mars since the human's that were evacuating were being sent to mars. Then when the machine shot off you could see the space shuttles for the humans at the same planet that got hit.

Comment: It should be aimed at Mars, theatrically. But the machine is ancient and would have no prior knowledge of the humans destination.